# Typescript: Property require does not exist on type 'typeof aceAjax'

Tags: typescript, ace-editor

I'm trying to create a custom autocompleter for the ace editor. All the documents i've read on it say i need to use `ace.require('ace/ext/language_tools')` to create an autocompleter. But I can't even get ace.require() to work. I'm not sure if i'm missing something in my package.json or the .ts file itself.

Example article I was following:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/How-to-enable-Autocomplete-in-the-Ace-editor

My package.json ace dependencies are set up like

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/ace": "0.0.36",
    "ace": "^1.3.0",
    "ace-builds": "^1.2.9",
    "brace": "^0.11.0"
},
```

My editor.ts file is simply:

```
import * as ace from 'brace';

class RqlEditor {
    private initAutocompleter(...irrelevant);

    public init(customMetadataProperties: String[]) {
        const langTools = ace.require('ace/ext/language_tools');

        langTools.addCompleter(this.initAutocompleter(customMetadataProperties));
        const editor = ace.edit('container');
        editor.setOptions({
            enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        });    
    }
}

export default RqlEditor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course after hours of searching, i find the answer 20 minutes after i ask the question. I'm using brace with webpack, so i just needed to `import 'brace/ext/language_tools`. And then instead of using ace.require, i used `ace.acequire('ace/ext/language_tools')`